# Chromium window fixed size and disable dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

I'm doing an application with chrome and java. I want to make the window with a fixed size (not resizable). Is there a start tag for this available? And how can I disable the strg-i shortcut for the developer tools? I need start tags for it like: --app-window-size... or any option accessible through a java process

I appreciate every answer.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two completely separate languages. Please clarify what exactly you're using. Are you starting chromium from the command line?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, Chrome and Chromium are not the same, are you using an instance of Chrome in your Java app, or an instance of Chromium? It also looks like JavaScript is not related to the question at all.

Comment: I have a java program hosting a web socket. This program starts chrome.exe 

(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:"+f+"Program Files"+f+"Google"+f+"Chrome"+f+"Application"+f+"chrome.exe "+ args.toString());) 

with some flags and the local java web server. The chrome instance opens the local webpage with a js script that connects to the java web socket. it's already working pretty well, the only issue is that the user can resize the window, breaking some HTML ui parts.

Comment: You are supposed to be able to resize the browser. If you want more control over what the user can do, maybe you could use electron?  https://www.electronjs.org/

Comment: The point is i want to make a gui in html with java as backend. It's working almost perfectly, the only issue is the problem with resizing. Electron uses chrome too, what was theire solution?